SwiftUI List not selectable in iOS 15
I am using a List in an app I'm developing. I just discovered that selecting an item from the List isn't working in iOS 15. It does work in iOS 16, 17 and 18. (I had to download the iOS 16 simulator to test that case.)
Here is a minimum reproducible example:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var array = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"]
    @State var selectedItem: Int? = nil
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Snork!")
            List(Array(array.enumerated()), id: \.offset, selection: $selectedItem) { index, item in
                Text(item).tag(index) // .tag suggested in comment
            }
            
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

If you run that code on an iOS 17 or 18 simulator, it lets you select a single list item.
If you run it on iOS 15.x, the List ignores taps. The items are not selectable.
I am still fairly new to SwiftUI. What am I missing?

Perhaps add a .tag(index to the Text? That might not have been automatic in the past.

No joy. That doesn't help. @BenzyNeez, do you have any suggestions?

Buried in the docs on List it says "Note: In iOS 15, iPadOS 15, and tvOS 15 and earlier, lists support selection only in edit mode, even for single selections." I haven't worked with edit mode for lists before, and don't want the list to have edit functionality. I'm unclear what puts a list in edit mode.

Ah, nice find! The same documentation page tells you how to go into edit mode. Either set the editMode environment value or EditButton. Edit mode also allows you to delete items (shows a delete button) and IIRC in iOS 15 you cannot disable that.

So apparently SwiftUI does not support selecting List items except in edit mode in iOS ≥ V16. It just doesn't work. Edit mode has a very different look than regular List selection, so it isn't a great choice if you have a specific UI you're trying to implement (in edit mode the list items have radio button looking things at the beginning.)
I guess I'm going to have to build something from scratch with a ScrollView, VStack, etc. Sigh...
